# facing error while trying to use git over HTTPS in MacOs Monterey. error:06FFF089:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad key length

Tags: git, macos, ssl, openssl, macos-monterey

I am trying the command "git pull" and facing the error.
This started after the MacOS upgrade to Monterey.
All my git commands fail with the below error.

fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.myenterprise.com:1234/smc/csm/my-service.git/': error:06FFF089:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad key length

I have tried the solution provided at a similar post
[Fixing git HTTPS Error: "bad key length" on macOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734654/fixing-git-https-error-bad-key-length-on-macos-12)

However, it did not work for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was facing this error when I use "git pull" or "git clone htttps://myrepo.git".


Any git command over HTTPS network.


this started when I updated MacOs to Monterey from BigSur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to continue using HTTPS:

```
export CURL_SSL_BACKEND="secure-transport"
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks  
this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use ssh instead of HTTPS.
However, with HTTPS I felt like I have more freedom to access the bitbucket anywhere with ease, I have to compromise with ssh.

I hope we get fix from Apple soon.